# Hypothesis Testing Confusion - Laboratory Mice

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I've slowly been building up some confidence on these types of problems but after the easy plug-n-chug I get very confused on what to do. There is a solution I found online for this question [(number 1, solution 1)](http://ieor.berkeley.edu/~ieor165/discussions/ieor165_dis6.pdf) but I get confused on the very last step, where they say .046 > .05.

The question is: A colony of laboratory mice consists of several thousand mice. The average
weight of all the mice is 32 grams with a standard deviation of 4 grams. A laboratory assistant
was asked by a scientist to select 25 mice for an experiment. However, before performing the
experiment, the scientist decided to weigh the mice as an indicator of whether the assistants
selection constituted a random sample or whether it was made with some unconscious bias
(perhaps the mice selected were the ones that were slowest in avoiding the assistant, which
might indicate some inferiority about this group). If the sample mean of the 25 mice was
30.4, would this be significant evidence, at the 5 percent level of significance, against the
hypothesis that the selection constituted a random sample?

My steps were:

Ho = mu-not is 32 grams (selection is random)

H1 = mu is not 32 grams (selection is not random)

standard deviation is 4 grams

n = 25 mice

x-bar (sample mean) = 30.4

Confidence Interval is 95% (level of significance is .05)

All I really did was find the p-value using: (x-bar - mu) / (std dev / sqrt(n))

p-value: |30.4 - 32| / (4/5) = 2

The probability of rejecting Ho = (Z > 2)

Value based on the confidence interval would be the level of significance divided by 2 since this is a two-sided confidence interval. Looking this up in a z-table I got 1.96. However, I don't know where to go from here especially since the solutions page has .046 < .05, which I'm not sure how to get. Can someone please explain this?

Comment: For $z=1.96$ you get a $p$-value of exactly $0.05$. so I except you have slightly miscalculated the $z$-score

Comment: I may have been able to step further: 2, looked upon the z-table, is .9772. The level of significance of this particular value would be 1-.9772 = .0228. Multiply this by 2 due to the two-sided interval, and I got .0456. If you say Z would be the given level of significance (.05), then we would plug this in(?) to check if the null hypothesis is rejected. .0456 > .05. Thus, the selection is not random?

Comment: Yes I think that's right, but be careful about your inequality signs, $0.0456<0.05$ which means it is significant at the $0.05$ level.  You have your inequality sign pointing the wrong way.

Comment: Oh, oops. I just noticed that. But, why would we not get the value from before? By that, I mean comparing 2 to 1.96. Is that just an incorrect way of trying to reject the null hypothesis?

Comment: You're right, you can compare $z$-scores without translating into $p$-values, as long as you know which $z$-score corresponds to the $0.05$ $p$-value cutoff.

Comment: Excellent, this is a lot clearer now. Thank you for the help.

Comment: No problem, keep up with it, this kind of significance testing is a very good skill to have.